# How to divide the class into 2 section where every child in each section are friends?

Tags: graph-algorithm

If you want to divide the class of n children into two sections and you know that some students pairs of students are friends with each other, and you want to try to split the two sections in such a way that in each section all students are friends of each other. What is an efficient algorithm to form the two sections given as input n, and m statements of the form `i and j are friends with each other'. What is the running time of your algorithm?

I tried to model the problem as an undirected graph, G where there are $n$ nodes and each child represents a node. Two nodes are connected by an edge if the two children are NOT friends.  We will get a bipartite graph with two disjoint sets, u and v. Where every child in each set is friends with each other.

Is this sufficient to output the correct answer?
How do you prove that it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is correct. You can also mark two nodes are connected if these two nodes are friends with each other. After processing all edges(friend relations), do a breath-first search or depth-first search to find out the number of connected components, in this problem, the number must be 2. Alternatively, you can use a Union-Find data structure to do the same thing.

The runtime of the above algorithms are all O(N + M), N is the number students, M is the number of friend relations.

The proof is pretty straightforward. We just need to prove the following 2 claims.

1. If we can divide all students into 2 groups, then the number of connected components must be 2.
2. If the number of connected components is 2, we can divide all students into 2 groups and satisfy the given requirement.

To prove claim 1, let's use contradiction. Say we can divide all students into 2 groups but the connected components count is not 2, then it will either be 1 or bigger than 2. In either case, you always end up with one group that are not fully connected.

claim 2 is self-evident.